# ufw doesn't block ports I expect it to block

Tags: ufw

I've installed `ufw` on my VPS and ran the following commands:

```bash
# ufw default allow outgoing
# ufw default deny incoming
# ufw allow ssh
# ufw allow 443/tcp comment 'accept HTTPS connections'
# ufw enable
# service ufw restart
```

The output of `ufw status` is

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                   # accept HTTPS connections
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # accept HTTPS connections
```

When I visit a <ip_address_of_vps>:**82** from my PC at home through the browser I still get a web page of a service running in a Docker container, which I want to shield from the internet. Why is port 82 still open?

Comment: @user68186 Docker opens firewall ports on the host machine on it's own and they are not displayed in the firewall output? That seems like a recipe for disaster...

Comment: You may find [How To Use Docker with a UFW Firewall](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-use-docker-with-a-ufw-firewall/) useful.